# Which Framework choosing for 3D animation on Android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, frameworks, 3d

I started to develop an Android application, and I would like to run a 3D animation at launch, showing a car in 3D. It will be my first experience, as a result I would like to know what framework i have to use?. I've heard about min3D but I can't find documentation to guide me in my development from A to Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to load 3D models with min3D, a tutorial: [see this link](http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/)

you can also see this project it seem it target your same goal sources are also attached, feel free to focus on it and get some benefis. [min3d car](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiM_liSVP7U&feature=results_main&playnext=1&list=PL91309EA881B7FDAC)

Comment: I didn't found how to download the min3D Framework(http://code.google.com/p/min3d/). There's just files with .apk extension!

Comment: go to the sources section not download section and you will find the source code grab the code and add it to your project like mentioned on the first link that i have give in my previous answer. you can use an svn do download all the source code, and add it to your project

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked also about choosing a framework, I want to recommend one more than the min3d. Take a look to Rajawali Framework.

There is big list of Rajawali tutorials [here](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali#tutorials). Also you can download [Android project with examples](https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliExamples) from github.

I'm very impressed with this library!

Comment: nice link, is there any other framework similar to Rajawali framework for iPhone,